# Error while creating Quick simple product for configurable product

Tags: configurable-product, error, image

Today I came across with one of the errors which is while creating a quick simple product for configurable product, i was getting an error which is:

> "An error occurred while saving the product. Image file was not found"

Can anyone please help me on this?

[image]

Comment: have you already create  configurable product??According magento,you need to configurable product first then simple

Comment: yes created and as a test when i try to remove images for a product by checking remove check box and then clicking on save button then immediately it's saying "image was not found" but i see those images in the folder. Not understanding how to resolve this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who comes up with this error, if you are trying to remove the images from the **parent product** at the same time, make sure you have product image placeholders as this error will occur if you do not.

You can check in `System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Product Image Placeholders`. If you can't see an image next to each of the three options, then you will need to add them. May not be your issue, but was in my case.